# how do I convert an arff file to libsvm file

Tags: svm, libsvm, arff

I am trying to convert an arff file into a libsvm file in my project,so can anyone help me in doing this, thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

I wrote my own python script to do this job:

```
import sys

if(len(sys.argv) < 3):
    print("usage: ./python convertToSVM.py inputfilename outputfilename")
#print sys.argv[1]

inputfilename = sys.argv[1]
fin = open(inputfilename,'r')
lines = fin.readlines()
fin.close()
outputfilename = sys.argv[2]
fout = open(outputfilename,'w')

beginToRead = False
for line in lines:
    if beginToRead == True:
        if len(line) > 5:# not an empty line
            #read this line
            dataList = line.split(',')
            resultLine = ''
            resultLine += dataList[-1].strip()
            resultLine += ' '
            for i in range(1,len(dataList)-1):
                resultLine += str(i)
                resultLine += (":"+dataList[i]+" ")
            #print(resultLine)
            fout.write(resultLine+"\n")

    if line[0:5] == '@data':
        beginToRead = True

fout.close()
```

This script can convert this kind of weka ARFF file specified in this [website](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html) to LIBSVM file specified in this [website](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/multiclass.html). I hope this script can help you.

To use this script, in the terminal, you can just type:

```
./python convertToSVM.py inputfilename outputfilename
```

The inputfilename is the input ARFF file, and the outputfilename is the filename of the output libsvm file.

Comment: I found this useful, but I believe there's a bug in this script at the innermost for loop:

`for i in range(1,len(dataList)-1):
                resultLine += str(i)
                resultLine += (":"+dataList[i]+" ")`

This skips the first data point of each row, should be:

    `for i in range(1,len(dataList)):
                    resultLine += str(i)
                    resultLine += (":"+dataList[i-1]+" ")`

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29892132/2827162) by Chang is fine, however, the script fails in cases where the class label is not the last entry in the Instance data.

The Weka built-in class `LibSVMSaver` ([doc](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable-3-8/weka/core/converters/LibSVMSaver.html)) is a better option for achieving the required results. It can be used from within projects and also from command line.